# Need to add to srting in postgresql select query result

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a bundle of tables in my database. I need to truncate all the tables but not some.

so by using table_schema i can get list of table names!

```
select  ''as "truncate", table_name 
from information_schema.tables 
where  table_schema = 'public'
```

Expected output.

```
truncate table table_name restart identity.
```

some one tell me is there any better way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `format()` with placeholders for the schema and table name to make sure the names are quoted properly:

To properly deal with the foreign keys used by the tables, it would also be better to add the `cascade` option to the `truncate` command:

```
select format('truncate table %I.%I restart identity cascade;', table_schema, table_name) as stmt
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public';
```

Another option would be to truncate all tables in a single statement:

```
select concat('truncate table ', string_agg(format('%I.%I', table_schema, table_name), ', '), ' restart identity;') as stmt
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'public'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `concat` strings in Postgres using `||`

```
select 'truncate table' || table_name::text || ' restart identity'
from information_schema.tables 
where table_schema = 'public
```

Take a look at [9.4. String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-string.html)